# "java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset" in linux server

Tags: java, linux, oracle

I have a java program which connect to oracle database sometimes it work and sometimes show me this error message :

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:498)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
```

How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Answer took from oracle forum, [**here**](https://community.oracle.com/message/3701989):

`java.security.SecureRandom` is a standard API provided by sun. Among various methods offered by this class `void nextBytes(byte[])`.

This method is used for generating random bytes. Oracle 11g JDBC drivers use this API to generate random number during
login. Users using Linux have been encountering `SQLException("Io exception: Connection reset")`.

The problem is two fold:

1. The JVM tries to list all the files in the /tmp (or alternate tmp directory set by -Djava.io.tmpdir) when
   `SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[])` is invoked. If the number of files is large the
   method takes a long time
   to respond and hence cause the server to timeout
2. The method `void nextBytes(byte[])` uses /dev/random on Linux and on some machines which lack the random
   number generating hardware the operation slows down to the extent of bringing the whole login process to
   a halt. Ultimately the the user encounters SQLException("Io exception:
   Connection reset")

Users upgrading to 11g can encounter this issue if the underlying OS is Linux which is running on a faulty hardware.

The cause of this has not yet been determined exactly. It could either be a problem in the hardware or the fact
that for some reason the software cannot read from `dev/random`

a **solution** seems to add this setting to the jvm

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Comment: where i can find this file? such i use linux??

Comment: Please explain what the underlying issue is and why this answer would solve it? If the answer is in the links then you should consider summarising the salient points in your answer.

Comment: i've just fixed my answer. @MohamedFenni you have to pass this setting to the jvm

Comment: i learn this two link and when i type $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security it show me no such directory so for this  i asked where i can find this file

Comment: try running your app from command line:  java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar yourAppName.jar

Comment: i run it in windows or linux?because i deploy my program to .jar and i use it in linux

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem but now when i execut the same program many times it take long time to be executed

Comment: could be the hardware issue stated above in point nr° 2.

Comment: i don't understand

Answer (score -1):

Connection reset usually happens when the connection between you app and the database gets disconnected for example network issue or resources that's required.

Check the following post it should give you an idea of what to check.
[SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110395/sqlrecoverableexception-i-o-exception-connection-reset)