# Connection to Oracle data base works on Windows but not on Ubuntu Using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm able to connect to a data base from Windows (Windows 10, via SQL Developer), **but not via Linux** (Ubuntu,via SQL Developer).

- The two operating systems run on the same client computer
- I use exactly the same connection information (I compared the screens from windows and linux), therefore the connection information is correct
- SQL Developer Version  is exactly the same (Version 18.3.0.277 Build 277.23.54)
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai98s.png)
- The firewall in ubuntu (ufw) is disabled, and telnet to [data-base-host]:[port] works. The data base server logs show that the ubuntu-client is connecting.

The error message which appears in oracle sql developer:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Connection reset by peer, Authentication lapse 0 ms.[Error message in Oracle SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S92GQ.png)

In Ubuntu I also tried with a different random source as suggested in [Oracle JDBC intermittent Connection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue), which didn't help. I also tried to connect with intellij idea and DB Driver versions (V12.1.0.2, V11.2.0.4) with the same results. The error message in IntelliJ:

> Connection to XXXX failed. [08006][17002] IO Error: Connection reset.

Version Details:

> Java Version: \openjdk version "1.8.0_191" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>   VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
>
> OS: Ubuntu Kernel Version:
>   4.18.0-11-generic
>
> Oracle SQL Developer Version: 18.3.0.277 Build 277.23.54

[Update]
With Oracle JDK 8, I still receive the same error.

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

In ~/.sqldeveloper/18.3.0/product.conf I changed the configuration to following settings, as suggested by thatjeffsmith. However the outcome was the same.

```
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
AddVMOption -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: my first thought is that we don't support OpenJDK - but that should not matter for this case - but you might try oracle jdk instead

Comment: and this one looks...like it could apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777075/java-sql-sqlexception-i-o-error-connection-reset-in-linux-server

Comment: I now also tried with java-8-oracle and adding urandom option to product.conf. However the outcome was the same.